# extract file name of url page from links

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm trying to extract the page names from a httpclient response. 
I want to use regex to extract all the links that are in the /bts format. (this part is working fine and im not gettin any undesired links)
ex:when the pattern is " bts/pagename.htm">Name of link " i want that pagename to be extracted.
I have it working to extract the full example above but I can't seem to extract just the page without the the rest of the pattern. The patten im matching is bts/  to   but I dont wanna keep them in my output. I guess really i want pagenames that start with bts/ and end in .htm
Maybe its impossible Im not sure

Comment: make your example a little more clear please.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to extract the character sequence of filename?

I'm not very good at regular expression. But maybe you can try this

```
(?<=/)\w+(?=.)
```